# Can I swap out Office 2010 Home with Office 2010 Professional?

Tags: microsoft-office

I have two laptops each with a copy of Office 2010. One is Home & Business and the other is Professional.

I need to have Publisher, which is part of the Professional package on the laptop that has the home version. I do not want to lose my mail and files. Is there a way to load from the DVD without uninstalling.

I have both discs and both keys. I just need to flip flop versions without losing anything on each machince.

Comment: If they are both your machines, then I think the Office license actually permits installing up to two instances. You should be able to legitimately have Pro on both laptops. However, I'm not a lawyer and don't have a copy of the license here to double-check.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling and reinstalling Office 2010 will not affect any of the documents you created with it.

The uninstaller should and will only remove the application files. You can then install with your Professional license and Home license respectively.

I recently downgraded from Professional to Home & Business myself and can't report any issues yet.